# Is O(n^2) greater than O((n^2)logn)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Is O(n^2) is greater than O(n^2 log n) ?
If yes  ? how ?
Can we have a simple example for this.
Also ,
What is complexity of the code below.

```
int unknown(int n){
   int i,j,k=0;
   for(i=n/2;i<=n;i++){
     for(j=2;j<=n;j=j * 2){
         k =k + n/2;
     }
  }
return k;
}
```

and What is complexity of return value k ?

Comment: This might be more suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (n^2)logn or n^(2logn) ?

Comment: Mitch Wheat : (n^2)logn

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`O(n^2)` is a *subset* of `O((n^2) * log(n))`, and thus the first is "better", it is easy to see that since `log(n)` is an increasing function, by multiplying something with it, you get a "higher" function then the original (`f(n) <= f(n) * log(n)` for each increasing non negative `f` and `n>2`)

The code snap you gave is `O(nlog(n))`, since the inner loop repeats `log(n)` times per outer loop iteration, and the outer loop repeats n/2 times - which gives you `n/2 * log(n)` which is in `O(nlog(n))`

Answer (score 2):

Ln(e) == 1, so anything greater than e (~2.7) will give Ln(n) > 1.

Therefore for all n where n > e, O(n^2 ln(n)) will be > O(N^2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean `O((n^2) * log n)`, but the answer is the same and what you need to prove is basically the same if it's `n^(2 * log n)`. I will also only consider non-negative functions, to save some messing about with absolute values.

The answer is that `O(n^2)` is a strict subset of `O((n^2) * log n)`. It is smaller.

First prove it's a subset: Suppose `f` is `O(n^2)`. Then there exist `M` and `k` such that for all `n >= M`, `f(n) <= k(n^2)`.

Let `L = max(M, e)` (where e is the logarithmic base). Then for all `n >= L`, `log(n) >= log(e) == 1` (since `n >= 1`) and `f(n) <= k(n^2)` (since `n >= M`).

Hence for all `n >= L`, `f(n) <= k(n^2) * log(n)`. So `f` is in `O((n^2) * log n)`.

Second, prove it's a strict subset: let `g` be the function `g(n) = (n^2) * log n`, so `g` is in `O((n^2) * log n)`.

For any `k`, take `L = e^k`. Then for any `n > L`, `log(n) > k` and so `g(n) > n^2 * k`.

Hence `g` is not in `O(n^2)`, since there cannot exist `M` and `k` such that for all `n >= M`, `g(n) <= k * n^2`.

Comment: Surely that should be (2 + log n) rather than (2 * log n)?

Comment: @Vatine: what should be `2 + log n`? If the question is "wrong" then you'll have to take that up with the questioner, but the question certainly doesn't say `2 + log n`.

Comment: You're saying that "(n^2) * log n" is "basically the same as n^(2 * log n)", the latter should probably be "(2 + log n)".

Comment: @Vatine: I'm saying that what you need to prove is basically the same. The functions are different. The form of the proof will be very similar, but with different choices of `L`. The reason I mention `n^(2 * log n)` is simply that what the question says, `n^2logn`, is ambiguous. For my answer I've gone with the bracketing in the title.